# "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" with math blocks

Tags: bug

Could anyone tell me why the site keeps telling me that

> "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
>   code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar
>   button..."?

The only way I was able to post [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202774/solve-pde-using-ansatz/202778#202778) was to replace all math blocks by code blocks.
Before this replacement the question was displayed properly in the preview window, except that line breaks in math mode were ignored.

Whether the parser is broken or not (and I heard from other's they think it is), I think it's a bit extreme to stop someone from posting just because some tool is not happy with formatting. A warning message sounds more appropriate.

**Update:**

This really seems to affect everything I'm posting. As another example, I just posted [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202853/why-wont-mathematica-give-a-prettier-expression-for-this-really-simple-algebrai). Another user removed the backticks that I had added to be able to post the question. Now the question is displayed the way it should but I cannot even make simple text changes anymore, unless I add the backticks back in. In fact, even just clicking "Edit" and then "Save Edits" without making any changes fails.

Comment: Could you upload the exact text of the question that's giving you problems somewhere, e.g. on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)? This would make reproducing the issue a lot easier

Comment: @LukasLang https://textuploader.com/11jwl If I try to edit my question to exactly that form I get the error message, even though the preview window displays everything perfectly (it doesn't even ignore my line breaks anymore)

Comment: See https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2040/4999 and https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2460/4999

Comment: @MichaelE2 what's the conclusion from that? Is someone working on this? Is it broken at all or did I have a subtle syntax mistake in my source? Why was someone able to edit the question I referred to successfully in the exact same way I tried to but failed? Does SE check the posts of new users more strictly?

Comment: The tag [tag:status-review] was put on the Q by mod @AdamLear, which is supposed to indicate that it is under review. There is also a complementary tag [tag:status-completed].

Comment: Can confirm that this is still a bug. [Here's the question I wanted to post](https://gist.github.com/paulrberg/5ad52bd1d05844f5eb068334835e51d5).

Comment: [I managed to post it eventually](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244140/how-to-use-power-with-numberform), but it wasn't obvious what I had to do to make it work (I basically moved all math blocks inline).