# How do I upload my question to this website?

Tags: support, bug, code-formatting, review

I'm unable to upload [this question](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7q677fjtjb4jvy/Average.docx?dl=0) to mathematica stack exchange. I get a message below the edit box which states, "Code is not formatted correctly." Please help if possible.

Comment: Here's a similar question: [Post contains a code that is not properly formatted](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2460/post-contains-a-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted)